# How to filter a concatenated value when using django tables2 and django_filters

Tags: django, django-tables2, django-filters

I am using django tables2 and django_filters to filter my value fields being on the table.

my models:

```
class Woo_Orders(models.Model):
    oid = models.IntegerField("oid",null=True)
    site=models.ForeignKey(Site, null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Site", on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Site(models.Model):
    ref_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="REF")
```

The `Site` is fk to the `Woo_Orders` model.

my table:

```
class WooOrderTable(tables.Table):
ref_prefix = tables.Column(accessor='site.ref_prefix',verbose_name= 'Ref Prefix')

class Meta:
        model = Woo_Orders
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
        exclude = (...,...)
        sequence = ('ref_prefix',...,...)


def render_ref_prefix(self,record):
        #site prefix + oid
        concatenated_prefix = record.site.ref_prefix + str(record.oid)
        return '%s' % (concatenated_prefix)
```

The return value is the concatenated value of `oid` value from the `Woo_Orders` model plus the `ref_prefix` value of `Site` model.

**My problem is that I do not know how to return the concatenated value when i filter on the `ref_prefix` field.**

my filter:

```
class WooOrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
   site__ref_prefix = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

class Meta:
        model = Woo_Orders
        fields = ['site__ref_prefix']
```

The filter is "catching" only the `ref_prefix` part of the `Site` model and not all the concatenated value as I want.

**How can i fix the filter part to search based on the concatenated value?**

Comment: Finally i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.

I have to declare in the filters.py file my custom column field like this:

```
site__ref_prefix = django_filters.CharFilter(label = "Site Prefix",method='my_custom_filter')
```

and beyond that to declare the method responsible for filtering.

```
class Meta:
        model = Woo_Orders
        fields = ['site__ref_prefix']

def my_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, site__ref_prefix):
        qs = Woo_Orders.objects.all()
        return qs.filter(Q(site__name__istartswith=site__ref_prefix) | Q(site__name__icontains=site__ref_prefix))
```